# how to create a class in ndk

Tags: android, performance, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I downloaded the [hello-jni](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html) sample project from google, within the hello-jni.c file, I created the following class:

```
class Test
{
    private:
     int x;

    public:

    int thisisPUblic=123;

};
```

However I am getting an error: can not resolve type class

How can I create a class within an NDK project?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use classes in C. Rename your source file hello-jni.cpp.

Comment: but that broke my Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI method, perhaps you can show me how to create a new cpp file and have it work in NDK?

Comment: If you rename the file, also change the name in 'LOCAL_SRC_FILES' in the Android.mk file

Comment: When renaming the `hello-jni.c` file to `.cpp`, you need to add `extern "C"` right before `jstring Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI`, or add a `extern "C" { ... }` block around it. If you'd use a header generated by `javah` to declare the functions, you wouldn't need to do this manually in the `.cpp` file though.